# Understanding "invariant differentials" of singular Weierstrass curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, schemes, arithmetic-geometry

$\newcommand\spec{\operatorname{spec}}\newcommand\P{\mathbb P}\newcommand\msO{\mathscr O}\newcommand\push[1]{{#1}_*}$
Say I have some relative Weierstrass curve $f:W\to S$ (so $f$ is flat and proper of finite presentation, it's geometric fibers are integral of genus 1, and there's a section $\sigma:S\to W$ landing in the locus where $f$ is smooth). Feel free to assume $S=\spec k$ if it simplifies things below.

Locally on the base, $W$ is of the form
$$\left\{Y^2Z+a_1XYZ+a_3YZ^2 = x^3+a_2X^2Z+a_4XZ^2+a_6Z^3\right\}\subset\P^2_U\text{ with }a_i\in\Gamma(U,\msO_U)$$
(where $U\subset S$ some small open), and given this description one can write down the expression
$$\alpha:=\frac{dx}{2y+a_1x+a_3}.$$
My question is about the right way to interpret this expression; what sort of object is it?

If $f$ is smooth, then I want to think of $\alpha$ as a section (over $U$) of the Hodge bundle $\push f\Omega^1_{W/S}$; it's really giving me some regular differential form on my curve over $U$. When $f$ is not smooth, I am under the impression that the sheaf of 1-forms is no longer the right object to have in mind, and I would like to be able to interpret $\alpha$ as a section (again, over $U$) of $\push f\omega_{X/S}$, where $\omega_{X/S}$ is the relative dualizing sheaf of $W\xrightarrow fS$. However, I do not know a concrete enough description of dualizing sheaves in order to make this rigorous.

It is maybe worth mentioning that (unless I'm mistaken) $\alpha$ still defines a section in $\Gamma(U^{sm},\push f\omega_{X/S})$ above the locus in $U$ where $f$ is smooth, but I really want a section over all of $U$ (and am not sure how to extend this over the singular part).

Is there a way of using $\alpha$ to define a section of $\push f\omega_{X/S}$? If not, is this expression just less useful in the presence of singularities, or is it just the case that the right way to think of it is not as a section of the Hodge bundle?

Comment: I think you are meant to interet this on the smooth locus only (e.g. as in Theorem 2.6 of http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/papers/minimalmodel.pdf). Why do you want to interpret it off the smooth locus?

Comment: I guess I wanted to interpret it off the smooth locus really because I was hoping it'd give me an example of writing down a section of the dualizing sheaf. At least if $S=\operatorname{spec}k$, then I believe $\omega_{X/k}$ is trivial and I'd like to know what a section actually looks like (e.g. so I can compute how it transforms as you move between these nice local models of $W$). I was hoping what one usually writes down in the smooth case would just magically work here too, but it sounds like this was too naive?